# Logging phone calls to Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

For a few years we've been using some JavaScript to log events (in this case phone calls) from our website to Google Analytics.  Recently, the code stopped working and I started to look into it.  From what I can tell Google deprecated the library that drives the code.  Is anyone else familiar with this technique?

Here is the code the stopped working.

```
<a href = "tel:5555555555"
title = "Click-to-Call for more information about our services"
onclick = "window._gaq &amp;&amp; _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'MobileLinks', 
'Phone', '30s - Your Health ' + new Date().toLocaleDateString()+' 
'+ new Date().toLocaleTimeString()]);" > <span> 
555 - 555 - 5555. < /span></a>
```

Thanks for any help you can lend me to make this code work again.

Answer (score 1):

Update your event tracking to the [latest specs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

Replace your `onclick` with:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'MobileLinks', 'Phone', '30s - Your Health '+ new Date().toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());"
```

Answer (score 0):

_gaq is a function of so-called 'Classic Google Analytics' library and it works from `.google-analytics.com/ga.js`
So if someone in your team switched to some other Google Analytics library then your code wouldn't work.
SO I suggest you checking the connected library on your page whether it is ga.js or `.google-analytics.com/analytics.js`